# Mukai exact sequence on a $K3$ surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a $K3$ surface. Let $C \subset X$ be a smooth curve on $X$. If we start with a base point free line bundle $A$ on $C$, then one can construct rank $2$ bundle $F$  by the Mukai exact sequence : $0 \to F^* \to H^0(A) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to A \to 0$. One can dualize the sequence to obtain the sequence : $ 0 \to H^0(A)^* \otimes \mathcal O_X \to F \to \mathcal O_C(C) \otimes A^*\to 0$.

Then I feel that  $F$ should be globally generated away from the base locus of the cokernel $\mathcal O_C(C) \otimes A^*$? Is there a concrete argument to show this?(  Moreover, can we say that the base locus is in dimension $1$? i.e. is it a curve?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $B = \mathcal{O}_C(C) \otimes A^*$.
Taking the cohomology of your second sequence, one obtains
$$
0 \to H^0(A)^* \to H^0(F) \to H^0(B) \to 0
$$
Tensoring this exact sequence by $\mathcal{O}_X$ and using functoriality of the evaluation morphism, we obtain a commutative diagram of evaluation morphisms, which implies
$$
\mathrm{Coker}(H^0(F) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to F) \cong
\mathrm{Coker}(H^0(B) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X \to B),
$$
which means that the base locus of $F$ (the support of the left-hand side) is equal to the base locus of $B$ (the support of the right-hand side).

Comment: thanks. I think you mean $B= \mathcal O_C(C) \otimes A^*$. Could you please direct to a source which discusses " functoriality of evaluation morphism" which seems to be the key ingredient of the argument. Finally is the support of the right hand side is codimension $1$?

Comment: Right (corrected). I think you can find functoriality of evaluation in the book "Fourier-Mukai transforms" by Huybrechts. The support of the RHS is contained in $C$, so it has codimension at least 1 in $X$ (and, say, if $C$ is irreducible and $H^0(B) \ne 0$, it has codimension 2 in $X$).

Comment: @ Sasha, so we can say $F$ is globally generated in codimension atmost $1$ in $X$ in general, right? and could you please refer to the particular theorem/ proposition dealing with "functoriality of evaluation morphism" in the book you just mentioned?

Comment: At least 1, not at most. And this is true in general (under your assumptions). Sorry, but I don't have time to search for the particular theorem in the book.